# How to export bookmarked phpmyadmin queries

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to migrate a database from one machine to another.

The db itself transfers fine, but a couple hours of searching have failed to find a way to transfer the saved (bookmarked) queries of PMA without copying and pasting them individually.

This is primarily for phpMyAdmin on a ubuntu machine but I'm not finding any answers for any software/OS combo.

Comment: `query` ? what do you mean ? function / procedure / trigger ?

Comment: What I mean is that I have about twenty saved/bookmarked SQL queries that are often run on the db and I'd like to export those with the db without resorting to copying them individually to a text file and then copying them back into the db after it's been moved.

Comment: Ok, I'm updated my answer, it's really easy ;)

Answer (score 2):

[edit] ok you're speaking of bookmark from PMA.

Then, on the left side of PMA, open the DB **`phpmyadmin`** and display the table **`pma__bookmark`**

You can export this table as usual, with the `export` option of PMA.

---

---

On phpMyAdmin / Version information: 4.5.4.1deb2ubuntu2 :

`export` > `Custom - display all possible options`

and take a look at the following :

[image: mysql options]